# Prevent user from clicking wrong button when editing a post

Tags: feature-request, answers, edits, alerts

So, I was just editing a post. Made my changes and I scrolled down and without thinking I accidentally clicked the "Post Your Answer" button. Immediately after clicking it, I was like "crap, wrong button" and it took me to the human verification screen because the post was empty (I hadn't typed anything into that box). I don't understand why that button was even enabled because all I even did was edit the post, I never even clicked in the answer textarea. But for some reason, the button *was* enabled.

Luckily, I was able to just click the back button and my browser remember the edits I had made so far, and I just clicked Save Edit.

**Imitating This Behavior:**
The "Post Your Answer" button appears to be enabled by default when I load a question. When I clicked it on accident and went back, it appeared as disabled. I tried this two more times, once just clicking the edit link, clicking Post Your Answer, and clicking back; the other just clicking Post Your Answer and clicking back. Whether or not I was in the edit screen didn't make any difference in this case. I'd assume it just remember it's disabled state due to JavaScript disabling it to prevent double submissions.

Also, this button being enabled appears to prevent the expected behavior of "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" when I'm in the edit screen, because I'm submitting a form, albeit empty.

**My suggestion:** Disable this button when a user loads the edit screen for a post, or maybe an alert to make the user confirm they really wanted to click this button if the edit screen is also open.